# Calculus III - Two Variables continuous function

Tags: calculus

Consider the function:
$$f(x,y)=
  \begin{cases}
    x^2y & x\in\mathbb Q,  \\
    y & x\notin\mathbb Q.
  \end{cases}
$$

- Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?
- Is $f$ continuous at $(0,1)$?
- For which $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb R^2$ does $f'_y(x_0,y_0)$ exist?

I started by dividing the function into :

$$f(x,y)= y *
  \begin{cases}
    x^2 & x\in\mathbb Q, \\
    1 & x\notin\mathbb Q.
  \end{cases}
$$

And now I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: There was an exactly same question asked yesterday.

Comment: I have been searching for half an hour and couldn't find any answer to this question. Seems like you guys just don't want to help, so you can keep the comments to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$:**

As $(x, y)$ tends to $(0,0)$, we have $x<1$, and so $x^2y<y$. Hence, it is enough to set $\delta = \epsilon$.

It is easy to see that **$f$ is not continuous at $(0,1)$** as it has no limit at this point!

For the next one, you may get the result by writing the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and considering the cases in which $x\in Q$ and in which $x\notin Q$ separately.